# How to get Binary Image in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, t-sql

I can use this function in c# to get the image binary

```
public static byte[] ImageToBinary(string imagePath)
{
            var fileStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + imagePath), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
            return buffer;
}
```

but I need to make the same in sql

I use this query

```
(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\0000001_computers_415.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS CategoryImage)
```

But I get an error:

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "C:\Users\0000001_computers_415.jpeg" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Comment: Does the file exist at that path on the database server you are running the query on?

Comment: Are you sure you want to have SQL Server read the image from disk? I would expect that whatever is calling the database, whether that's a web app, scheduled task, service, or whatever, should probably be the one that opens the image file.

Comment: Just to be sure.  You are running the query from the same machine that you are copying to file to, correct?  I noticed you posted elsewhere about an issue with linked servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL Server can only find files of it's own context. You must either copy the file into a directory on your SQL Server's machine to access it with local rights or you must define a shared path and let your SQL Server read from there.

Your `c:\users\...` is very likely your own local machine's drive.